# Swift : UITabBarItem custom image problems

Tags: swift, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I am trying to implement a custom TabBar with unselected and selected images. I used a custom UITabBarItem and used my images. the first result was this after using Image Inset +6 Top -6 Bottom.:
[image]

but left/right TabBarItems are kinda over each other. I tried using the right/left inset but this is not working properly. And also if I use left/right inset when I press again an already selected TabBarItem it shrinks.

What I want :
[image]

Note * unpressed images are 82x64 , pressed images are 81x60

Comment: post some code where you set insets

Comment: I use the storyboard